# replacing letters in a string if they are in a string of letters

Tags: python, regex, string

I have already checked to see if there is a solution for my question, before asking this one.

I am doing python. I am attempting to write code that takes a input string and for each letter in that string that is a vowel (`aeiou`), replace that vowel with itself 4 times. Then add an exclamation point (`!`) at the end. Example:

`apple` would then look like `aaaappleeee!`.

I have tried multiple times to make this work with no effect. Wondering if you guys can take a look at my code and see what I have been doing wrong. Hugs and kisses. Christopher

```
def exclamation (string):
    for i in range(0,len(string)):
        if string[i] in 'aeiou':
            string.replace(string[i],string[i*4])
        print(string + '!')
```

Comment: `string.replace` doesn't modify the string, it returns a new string with the replacements.

Comment: Also, `string.replace` will replace the _first_ copy of the letter it finds, or _all_ of them; anything but the particular copy you're trying to replace, because it has no way of knowing which copy you're trying to replace. So, if you the word "already", it would see the first `a` and give you `aaaalready`, then see the e and give you `aaaalreeeeady`, then see the second `a` and give you `aaaaaaalreeeeady`, and so on. `replace` is almost never what you want.

Comment: Also, `string[i*4]` is not the same thing as `string[i]*4`. The first one is going to give you a character from way later in the string, or raise an `IndexError`.

Comment: Finally, as a side note: The only reason to ever loop `for i in range(len(spam)):` is when you actually need the number `i` itself for some reason. If you just need the `i`th character, just do `for c in spam:`.

Comment: @abarnert thank you for your detail you have helped me greatly

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression for this:

```
def exclamation(string):
    newString = re.sub(r'([aeiou])', r'\1\1\1\1', string)
    return newString + '!'
```

Comment: You forgot to group the match `newString = re.sub(r'([aeiou])', r'\1\1\1\1', string)`

Answer (score 0):

Strings are immutable so replacing the string returns a new string every time. Instead just build a string as you go along like this:

```
def exclamation (string):
    buildString = ""
    for i in range(0,len(string)):
        if string[i] in 'aeiou':
            buildString = buildString +string[i]*4
        else:
            buildString = buildString +string[i]
    print buildString+"!"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def exclamation(string):
    new_string = ''
    for c in string:
        if c in 'aeiou':
            new_string += c * 4
        else:
            new_string += c
    new_string += '!'
    return new_string
```

Answer (score 0):

`replace` don't modify the existing string, it return. one more thing never modify list, string or dictionary while iterating over it. using `string` as variable name is bad practice.

```
def exclamation(my_string):
    new=''
    for i in range(0,len(my_string)):
        if my_string[i] in 'aeiou':
            new += my_string[i]*4
        else: new += my_string[i]
    print(new + '!')
```

output:

```
>>> exclamation('abcdef')
aaaabcdeeeef!
```

using `lambda` and `map`:

```
>>> def exclamation(my_string):
...     return "".join(map(lambda x:x in 'aeiou' and x*4 or x,my_string))+'!'
... 
>>> exclamation('abcdef!')
'aaaabcdeeeef!'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over a string, so you don't have to mess with range, and `str.replace` doesn't modify the existing string. Taken together, you can just do this:

```
def exclamation(string):
    for c in "aeiou":
        string = string.replace(c, c*4)
    print(string + "!")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use list comprehension:

```
>>> def exclamation(s):
...    return ''.join([x*4 if x in 'aeiou' else x for x in 'apple']) + '!'
... 
>>> exclamation('apple')
'aaaappleeee!'
```